# Composite label for checkbox

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have this page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label class="Label">Options</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" aria-checked="false">
      <label for="checkbox1">content 1</label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

which looks like this:
[image]

When I use Microsoft narrator (to check my website accessibility), I want the user to know that "content 1" is associated with "Options"
I tried to use aria-label:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" aria-checked="false" aria-label="options">
<label for="checkbox1">content 1</label>
```

But then the narrator reads only "options" and skip the "content 1".
What am I missing here?
I would like the narrator to read "options" and "content 1" when marking the checkbox.

Comment: Label and checkbox are associated, so whats the problem, dont use the aria-label.

Comment: In the first examples, the narrator does not associate the "Content 1" checkbox as part of the "Options"

Comment: What do you mean by not associate. I tested using a screen reader and it reads out Content 1 for that particular checkbox. (1st Example)

Comment: Show us where it doesnt work.

Comment: It is hard to show (because the narrator is a sound effect).
But basically the narrator reads "content 1" in the first examples, and "options" in the second.
I want the narrator to read both.

Comment: There's no reason to use `aria-checked` with native html checkboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I use VoiceOver but hopefully this would work with your screen reader of choice.*

---

If I understand correctly you want screen readers to announce both "Options" and "content 1" or to somehow let screen readers know that both are related.

**Option 1: Use native semantic**

Probably your best bet is to rely on semantic HTML:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Options</legend>
      <input type="checkbox" name="opts" id="cb1">
      <label for="cb1">Content 1</label>
    </fieldset>
  </body>
</html>
```

*Note: with a bit of CSS you can remove the default browser styles for fieldsets.*

Here's how Voice Over announces the checkbox:

[image]

**Option 2: compose label from other elements on the page**

Another option is to use `aria-labelledby` which takes a list of html ids and screen readers will form a sentence with the corresponding html elements:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <div id="group">Options</div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="opts" id="cb1" aria-labelledby="group label1">
      <label for="cb1" id="label1">Content 1</label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's how Voice Over announces it:

[image]

---

### Addendum: don't use `aria-checked` with native checkboxes

If you rely on native checkboxes and don't intend to programmatically control them then you have no reason to use `aria-checked`. Let the browser do the work for you; screen reader users will thank you ;)

Here's an example of an author wanting to preselect a checkbox with `checked="checked"` but left a `aria-checked="false"` attribute.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" checked="checked" aria-checked="false">
    <label for="cb1">content 1</label>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's how Voice Over announces the checkbox:

[image]

As you can see the screen reader is confused and think the checkbox is not checked. **If the screen reader user wanted to check it, they would actually uncheck the box!**

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that **aria-label replaces any other label association** rather than completing it.
That's why screen readers only says "content 1" and not "options".

More generally, aria-labelledby takes precedence over aria-label, which itself takes precedence over an association with a `<label>`.
The three can never be combined.

If you can, the best is to use a correctly associated `<label>`.
As already said by other answers, use `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` for grouping.

If the label that has to be announced effectively comes from several different elements, and if there is no notion of grouping, then you can use aria-labelledby.
Aria-labelledby allows you to specify several ids, which will be concatenated to make a single label for screen readers.
The first rule of ARIA is to not use it if you don't really need to though, so prefer `<label>` and `<legend>` as much as you can before using ARIA.

Comment: The truth is opposite to what is stated here about precedence. “user agents give precedence to aria-labelledby over aria-label when computing the accessible name property”. https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-labelledby

Comment: I corrected the answer about precedence, thank you. The rest of my answer still remains true.